# Docker Compose build order and/or firewall/networking error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

**Please note:** even though I *mention* Java and Spring Boot here, this is 100% a Docker/Docker Compose networking issue at heart, and as such, can be answered by anyone experienced with the Docker ecosystem, regardless of their familiarity with Java and Spring.

---

I have a Spring Boot (Java) web service that uses a MySQL database for its data layer. I have containerized it with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as cce

COPY application.yml application.yml
COPY my-service-local-keystore.p12 my-service-local-keystore.p12
COPY build/libs/my-service.jar my-service.jar

EXPOSE 9200

ENTRYPOINT [ \
    "java", \
    "-Dspring.config=.", \
    "-Dspring.profiles.active=${MY_ENV}", \
    "-Ddb.hostAndPort=${MY_SERVICE_DB_HOST}:${MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT}", \
    "-Ddb.name=MY_service_db_${MY_ENV}", \
    "-Ddb.username=${MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER}", \
    "-Ddb.password=${MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD}", \
    "-Dkeystore.file=my-service-local-keystore.p12", \
    "-Dkeystore.password=${MY_SERVICE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}", \
    "-jar", \
    "my-service.jar" \
]
```

To manage containers of this image as well as its backing MySQL DB at the same time, I have written the following `docker-compose.yml` file that goes in the same directory as the `Dockerfile` above (which is the root directory of my web service project):

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-service-db:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: $MY_SERVICE_DB_HOST
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - $MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT:$MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_service_db_$MY_ENV
      MYSQL_USER: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./my-service-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  my-service:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - my-service-db
```

In the same project root directory I also have the following `.env` file:

```
MY_ENV=local
MY_SERVICE_DB_HOST=my-service-db
MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT=3306
MY_SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123
MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER=my-service-user
MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD=def456
MY_SERVICE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=abcdef123456
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, I see both web service and MySQL containers spin up, but shortly thereafter the web service container dies/stops. When I follow the logs (before it dies), it complains about not being able to connect to MySQL (which the service needs to be able to do at startup time).

Interestingly enough, I *can* connect to the MySQL database from a MySQL client running on my host machine, and I make that connection over `0.0.0.0:3306`. So I *believe* the MySQL container is configured and running correctly.

FWIW I have tried changing the `MY_SERVICE_DB_HOST` env var (in `.env`) from `my-service-db` to `0.0.0.0` but it makes no difference.

So my only two guesses at this point are, either:

1. Somehow the web service container is being ran/spun up first, and since the MySQL container doesn't yet exist, it can't connect and it dies; or
2. There are Docker networking issues at play here such that another Docker container can't connect to the MySQL container over `0.0.0.0:3306`, but a MySQL client running on the host can

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to troubleshoot either or these two possibilities, and I'm sure there are others that I don't even know to think of! Any ideas where I might be going awry here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure Spring properties with environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).  In a Docker context, this is usually much easier than trying to inject them via the command line.  Depending on what they are, you can either provide them via `ENV` directives in the Dockerfile, or with Compose `environment:` settings.

There's a further syntactic problem with the command line you show.  If you use the [JSON-array form of `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) (or `CMD` or `RUN`) absolutely no substitution of any sort happens here.  You are setting the Java property `spring.profiles.active` to the literal string `${MY_ENV}`, not to the value of an environment variable.  (For a couple of reasons I won't go into here, I tend to prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` if you don't need both.)

So you can update the `Dockerfile` to look like:

```sh
# As in the original, mostly
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as cce
WORKDIR /app
COPY application.yml application.yml
COPY build/libs/my-service.jar my-service.jar
EXPOSE 9200

# Set fixed environment variables for Spring properties (or defaults)
ENV SPRING_CONFIG=.
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development

# Then set the main command to be run, without setting properties
CMD ["java", "-jar", "my-service.jar"]
```

And the corresponding `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  my-service-db: { ... unchanged ... }
  my-service:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - my-service-db
    # Inject the keystore file
    volumes:
      - ./my-service-local-keystore.p12:/app/my-service-local-keystore.p12
    # Set Spring properties through environment variables
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "${MY_ENV}"
      DB_HOSTANDPORT: "${MY_SERVICE_DB_HOST}:${MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT}"
      DB_NAME: "MY_service_db_${MY_ENV}"
      DB_USERNAME: "${MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER}"
      DB_PASSWORD: "${MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD}"
      KEYSTORE_FILE: /app/my-service-local-keystore.p12
      KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: "${MY_SERVICE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}"
```

Compose will [substitute values from the host environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution), so this passes values into the container in the appropriate properties.